# Cannot transfer torch.Tensor to torch.cuda.Tensor

Tags: python, pytorch, tensor

I use the following code to turn the torch.Tensor into torch.cuda.Tensor

```py
import torch
import numpy as np

a = np.random.randn(1, 1, 2, 3)

t2 = torch.tensor(a)
t2 = t2.cuda()

t3 = torch.tensor(a, device=torch.device('cuda'))
print(type(t3), t3.device, type(t2), t2.device)
```

And its output is
`<class 'torch.Tensor'> cuda:0 <class 'torch.Tensor'> cuda:0`

I expect the class is 'torch.cuda.Tensor'. I don't know why this happens.
My torch version is 1.6.0 and the corresponding cuda version is 10.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because there is no such class as `torch.cuda.Tensor` in PyTorch 1.6.0.

The `t3.device` and `t2.device` in `print(type(t3), t3.device, type(t2), t2.device)` prints `cuda:0` which means your tensors are already on GPU.

Comment: Then I tried it from torch.FloatTensor to torch.cuda.FloatTensor, but it doesn't work too. I don't know why it can't transfer to tensor for cuda.

Comment: update the answer.